# What is the difference between link and ld command in linux ..?

Tags: hard-link, ld

#### First, let tell what do I think about them:-

#### ld

ld is a GNU linker according to man page. I think, It takes an object file as input and return an executable output file. **ld combines a number of object and archive files, relocates their data and ties up symbolreference.**
for more information about ld visit: https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Linker.pdf

#### link

link is OASIS linker. I think, It also takes a compiled object file as input and return an executable output file. **The OASIS Linkage Editor is a command program that is used to "link" together the output of an assembly or compilation process into an executable load module.**
for more information about oasis linker visit http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/phaseOneSystems/oasis/Linkage_Editor_Reference_Manual_Mar80.pdf

Comment: the latter manual is from 1980 and documents not a Linux command but one component of the historical OASIS operating system. Are you sure that's what you meant to reference?

Comment: yes I'm. you visit second the link I share. I'm refering to that documentation

Comment: So, is the two thing that I mentioned in the question are same thing or they have a difference .??

Comment: perhaps I was unclear. the `link` command on a typical Unix system is equivalent not to `ld` but to `ln`. The OASIS Linkage Editor is a part of a non-Unix-like commercial system, OASIS. Sure that is comparable to GNU's `ld`, but it isn't "in linux" so the software in the question doesn't very well match the title

Comment: so, If I want to assemble an object code made by an assembler, which one should I use..? gnu linker(ld) or oasis linker(link)..?

Comment: Unless you're running OASIS, the defunct operating system from forty years ago, you're not using its linker. The compiler (e.g. `gcc`) tends to be a wrapper script that calls the linker as appropriate anyway. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm using kali linux. and in my system I have both the commands link/ln and ld. so, which one should I use...? I'm confused

Comment: have you read the manpages? The `link` command on a typical SUS-compliant system (any Unix-like) is _not_ the same kind of program as OASIS's "LINK" command. `link` produces (hard) links in the filesystem. But calling `ld` manually is also usually not necessary, since the compiler does it for you. So what are you actually trying to do? What problem prompted this question?

Comment: OOkha. so, You are saying the link command in my linux system is different than the documentation http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/phaseOneSystems/oasis/Linkage_Editor_Reference_Manual_Mar80.pdf

Comment: Absolutely. Scouring the internet for documentation is far from ideal when, say, `man link` is actually guaranteed to describe your own system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122704/discussion-between-fox-and-abdul-kuddus).

Comment: I was assembling an assembly program using NASM. so, after creating an object file using NASM, I'had to use ld command to make and executable file. This is saying in nasm or assembly language documentation. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Then according to your tutorial, `ld` is the way to go. But also in `man nasm` you probably see a "See Also" section near the bottom that would also direct you to `ld`